# How to check Mail Read or Unread Property (Lotus Notes) using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I want to check mail read and unread property using C#.
i.e want to check whether mail is read or not. (using Domino.dll)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unread marks table is not exposed through the "back-end classes" (which is what you are most likely using with Domino.dll). This is available thorugh the lower level C API - it's a bit more work to deal with, but if you are interested, look at the "NSFDbGetUnreadNoteTable", which takes a database handle and returns a handle to an "IDTable" (essentially, a document collection).

[IBM Documentation](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/7.0/api70ref.nsf/61fd4e9848264ad28525620b006ba8bd/683a9d787a2c9015852561bd00669930?OpenDocument)