# Problem in getting UnprocessedDocuments and CurrentDatabase using C# (domino.dll)

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

I trying below code:

NotesSession = _lotesNotesSession.GetDatabase("", NsfFile, false);

_NewDatabase = _NotesSession.CurrentDatabase; ( Note : Showing "Not Implemented" exception.)

_UnreadDocCollection = _NewDatabase.UnprocessedDocuments;

Here i am trying to get list of Read and Unread Mails From Nsf File.

Explanation: When i am using _NotesSession.CurrentDatabase it's trowing "Not implemented" Exception for CurrentDatabase.

Comment: Fine, and what's your question? And maybe your exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CurrentDatabase property of NotesSession is not available if you are running outside of Notes/Domino (ie: COM). Also, the UnprocessedDocuments attribute is only available in the context of a Domino agent. UnporocessedDocuments does NOT provide you a collection of "unread" documents - this is different, and as far as i know is not exposed to the COM classes - you will need to access the unread documents list from the C API.

See SO question #[1592940](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592940/how-to-check-mail-read-or-unread-property-lotus-notes-using-c)

Notes C API documentation for collecting unread documents is available here:
http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/tools/c/7.0/api70ref.nsf/61fd4e9848264ad28525620b006ba8bd/683a9d787a2c9015852561bd00669930?OpenDocument